# How do I hide HTML tags with PHP?

Tags: php, html

How do I hide the html tags when the user is not logged on for the users name to be display?

```
<li><a href="#" title="#"><?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { echo $_SESSION['first_name']; } ?></a></li>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) { ?>
<li><a href="#" title="#"><?php echo $_SESSION['first_name']; } ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

or with short tags:

```
<? if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) { ?>
<li><a href="#" title="#"><?= $_SESSION['first_name']; } ?></a></li>
<? } ?>
```

You can also use the [alternate PHP control structures](http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), which arguably make it more readable:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']): ?>
<li><a href="#" title="#"><?php echo $_SESSION['first_name']; } ?></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

With PHP you determine whether to spit out any content, you don't need to "hide" it per se like CSS...

```
<?php

if ( isset( $_SESSION['user_id'] ) ) {

?>

<li><a href="#" title="test"><?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'];?></a></li>

<?php

} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { echo "<li><a href=\"#\" title=\"#\">"; echo $_SESSION['first_name']; echo "</a></li>"; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this.

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['user']['id']):?>
<p>
    Hi <?=$_SESSION['user']['name'];?>, you are logged in!
</p>
<?php else:?>
<a href="/user/signin">Sign in</a> or <a href="/user/register">Register</a>
<?php endif;?>
```